# PHP function won't print message with variable

Tags: php, function, variables

So I'm trying to create some sort of error messages, code looks like this:

```
function callError($errorcode, $attempts) {
    $errormessage = array(
        "0" => "Du har angivit fel lösenord, du har ". $attempts ." försök kvar. Kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn.",
        "1" => "Ditt konto har låsts, kontakta webmaster för att återställa det.",
        "2" => "Användare finns inte, kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn."
    );

    return $errormessage[$errorcode];
}
```

but when I run the first error message it doesn't work, it won't even show up. On the other hand when I run the other two it works flawless! I've tried to return an array containing $errormessage and $attempts but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What about making it associative but without numbers as strings? Meaning `0 => array(), 1 => array() ...`

Comment: Get rid of the numbers like @fedorqui said and show us how you're calling this function

Comment: You probably get an `$errorcode` into the `callError()` function that isn't `0`, `1` or `2` or it fails to comply to the typecast from an `integer` to a `string`. It's much better to use try-catch-throw mechanisms :)

Comment: `var_dump($errorcode)`.......

Comment: @fedorqui That was the solution, thanks a bunch! I think I'm getting pretty tired..

Comment: Nice! A lot of eyes are normally faster to find errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem on type of variables.

Make sure you are consistent on this. For example, let's decide we want the values to be `int`:

```
function callError($errorcode, $attempts) {

    $errorcode = (int) $errorcode;
    $errormessage = array(
        0 => "Du har angivit fel lösenord, du har ". $attempts ." försök kvar. Kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn.",
        1 => "Ditt konto har låsts, kontakta webmaster för att återställa det.",
        2 => "Användare finns inte, kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn."
    );

    return $errormessage[$errorcode];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a switch with a fallback safety mechnism.

```
function callError($errorcode, $attempts) {
    $output = '';

    switch((int)$errorcode) {
        case 0:
            $output = 'Du har angivit fel lösenord, du har '. $attempts .' försök kvar. Kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn.';
            break;
        case 1:
            $output = 'Ditt konto har låsts, kontakta webmaster för att återställa det.';
            break;
        case 2:
            $output = 'Användare finns inte, kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn.';
            break;
        default:
            $output = 'SOMETHING WENT WRONG [CUSTOM MESSAGE]'.$errorcode.' : '.$attempts;
            break;
    }

    // Do something more here with your error handling if needed

    // Return the output message
    return $output;
}
```

This will force typecast `$errorcode` to an Integer. But it doesn't really matter for the `default` case, yet it will rule out problems with integers inside a string `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure index is String
Add

```
$errorcode = "$errorcode";
```

as the first line in the func

Comment: how about just making sure the numbers arnt strings as that is the easier option

Comment: This is pretty ancient PHP. And is not a safe solution for his problem sadly. It's better if he handles `switch cases` and has a `default` to fall back to.

Comment: @Allendar, I agree, was just providing a solution. Switch sounds like the better way of going what Jake wants.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: change that to a `switch()` statement:

```php
function callError($errorcode, $attempts) {
    switch ($errorcode) {
        case 0:
            return "Du har angivit fel lösenord, du har ". $attempts ." försök kvar. Kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn.";
        case 1:
            return "Ditt konto har låsts, kontakta webmaster för att återställa det.";
        case 2:
            return "Användare finns inte, kontrollera att du har skrivit rätt användarnamn.";
        default:
            return "No error associated";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was just to remove the numbers that were stringed in the array.

See @fedorqui comment!